# converting string into Boolean value using JavaScript always give false

Tags: javascript

I am using the code below in JavaScript to change a string on the site to a Boolean value using JavaScript. when I alert test its says its true, but when I alter name bool is see flase any ideas why this would be the case.

```
var test = document.getElementById("name").value;
var nameBool= (String == test);
```

Comment: What what what are you doing? `oO` Are you trying to make `"true"` become `true` or what?

Comment: What do you get when you put `alert(typeof(test));`?

Comment: `String` is the global String constructor function… Do you really want to compare against that? What is your actual code? Please show us *how* you "*alter name bool*", and what that `#name` element is

Comment: Could you please show a complete example with actual values? I doubt you actually compare the field value to `String` (or if you do, there's your problem).

Comment: Yoda coding! I thought that was a legend!

Comment: @pjmorse Where do you see Yoda coding?

Comment: yea i want "true" to become Boolean ture

Comment: @VisioN: `test == String` I guess, but anyhow I think op is looking for `typeof test == 'string'`

Comment: @elclanrs Nope `:P` Well, personally I wouldn't call that pure Yoda programming style, as if it is `"string" === typeof test`.

Comment: @pjmorse: WordPress coding standards use Yoda conditions http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/#yoda-conditions. I personally like it don't...

Answer (score 2):

Compare the string to the value that you expect it to have when it should represent a true value:

```
var nameBool = test === "true";
```

Comment: Isn't that too easy for the question? `;)`

Comment: this wont work when the value is false.. because at time it can be true or false and i dont want to be comparing strings as it nor completely accurate

Comment: @user2369743 The value of an HTML input field is a string, whether you like it or not. This is the correct answer.

Comment: @Juhana: Not of checkboxes, `type="number"` inputs etc?

Comment: @user2369743: The boolean value will only be `true` when the value from the input field is the string `"true"`. (The value from an input field is always a string.) If the value is `"false"`, then the boolean variable will be `false`, just as it will with any other string that is not exactly `"true"`.

Comment: @Juhana: Uh, of course. I had implicitly used their respective special properties :-/

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that `test` is the boolean value of a checkbox? Then you would get a textual representation of it either by

```
var nameBool = String(test); // type conversion
```

or simpler

```
var nameBool = "" + test; // concatenation with empty string - implicit conversion
```

which then becomes `"false"` or `"true"`, just as in your `alert()` (which did a stringification as well)

---

For the opposite, you'd use

```
var test = "true" // or "false"
var nameBool = test === "true" || (test === "false" ? false : throw new SyntaxError("non-boolean string value"));
```

Comment: Seems like the OP wants absolutely opposite.

Comment: What if you add `toLowerCase()`?

Comment: @VisioN: Where? To allow `"TrUe"` to become `true`? Why not also allow `"wahr"`/`"falsch"`/`"wrai"`/`"faux"`/…

Comment: Because I didn't like the OP's note that the value comes from the input field, and *"because at time it can be true or false and i dont want to be comparing strings as it nor completely accurate"*... Who knows what he really means.